# Does $\exists x\in\Bbb{R}$, such that, $\forall y\in\Bbb{R}, x<y \implies e^{f(x)-g(x)}<e^{f(y)-g(y)}$ make sense?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, induction, quantifiers

This is the problem I have:

> In this problem, assume all functions have domain $\Bbb{R}$. I will define two new concepts.
>
> 1. We say that $f$ is nicer than $g$ if
>    $$\exists x \in \Bbb{R}, s.t. \forall y \in \Bbb{R}, x < y \implies e^{f(x) - g(x)} < e^{f(y) - g(y)}$$
> 2. We say that $f$ is stronger than $g$ if
>    $$\forall x \in \Bbb{R}, \exists y \in \Bbb{R}, s.t. x < y \text{ AND } e^{f(x) - g(x)} < e^{f(y) - g(y)}$$

In sentence 1, it says $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$, such that, $\forall y \in \Bbb{R}, x<y \implies e^{f(x)-g(x)} < e^{f(y)-g(y)}$.
I am confused what this actually means. Does it mean that, for any $x$ that is in $\Bbb{R}$, we need to select those $y$ which are greater than $x$?

If "such that" was placed after $\forall y \in \Bbb{R}$, then this sentence would be:
$$\exists x \in \Bbb{R}, \forall y \in \Bbb{R},\text{ such that, }x<y \implies e^{f(x)-g(x)} < e^{f(y)-g(y)}$$
and wouldn't make any sense, since that would imply that every number real number taken as $y$ is greater than arbitrary $x$.

My argument is that, since "such that" is placed right after $\exists x \in \Bbb{R}$, we are only considering those $y$ that are greater than $x$ and hence $x<y$ is true and makes sense.

I am a little confused, so kindly throw some light on if I am correct or wrong, please.

Comment: The formulation in the title of your question would usually be understood, but it would be more accurate to omit "such that".  The existential quantifier by itself already means "there exists ... such that". An equivalent way to read $\exists$, that doesn't tempt people to add a redundant "such that" is "for at least one value of".

Comment: $e^a<e^b$ iff $a<b,$ so the exponent in the definition is  superfluous.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I've never thought about this ambiguity before. I usually include the "such that", because it makes the symbols nicely human-readable from left to right ("$\exists$ = "there exists", $x \in \Bbb{R}$ = "$x$ in the reals", "$\text{s.t.}$" = "such that", etc). Now that it's pointed out to me, I can definitely see how some could read this incorrectly.

Comment: “$\exists x$ means if needs to be true for at least one $x.$ $\forall y$ means  it needs to be true for all y. So “There is  some $x$ such that for  all $y$,…”

Comment: “Such that” here is a meaningless phrase, and also bad form to mix language with symbols. After $\exists x,$ it is implied that the rest of the sentence is “such that…” Formal math has no “such that” symbol. (There is a symbol used on blackboards as a substitution for the phrase, but it is a language substitution. First and second order logic do not use it.)

Comment: @TheoBendit, thanks, so would (i) imply that there exists a certain x for all y such that, x is going to be less than all y ?

Comment: @SnehilGupta No, so the says, there exists a certain $x$ so that for all $y \in \Bbb{R}$, whenever $y > x$, we also have $e^{f(x) - g(x)} \le e^{f(y) - g(y)}$. Basically, it takes the form $(\exists x)(\forall y)P(x, y)$, which is to say, there is a some $x$ so that $P(x, y)$ is true for all $y$. e.g. if $P(x, y)$ said $x + y = y$, then $(\exists x)(\forall y)P(x, y)$ is true, simply using $x = 0$. In this case, $P(x, y)$ takes the form $(x < y) \implies \ldots$, which is automatically true when $y \le x$ (this is how logical $\implies$ works), and otherwise true if $\ldots$ is true.